# Regular expression with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm having hard time selecting from a file using a regular expression. I'm trying to replace a specific text in the file which is full of lines like this.

/home/user/test2/data/**train**/train38.wav /home/user/test2/data/train/train38.mfc

I'm trying to replace the bolded text. The problem is the i don't know how to select only the bolded text since i need to use .wav in my regexp and the filename and the location of the file is also going to be different.

Hope you can help

Best regards,
Jökull

Comment: Perhaps you could define the strings to be replaced more precisely.  Is it the string between the 5th and 6th / for instance ?  Or is it always the word 'train' ?  Or is it the word which ends .wav, but in the segment before where it ends with .wav ?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that what you want to replace is the string between the last two slashes in the first path.

```
sed 's|\([^/]*/\)[^/]*\(/[^/]* .*\)|\1FOO\2|' filename
```

produces:

```
/home/user/test2/data/FOO/train38.wav /home/user/test2/data/train/train38.mfc
```

Answer (score 1):

sed processes lines one at a time, so you can omit the global option and it will only change the first 'train' on each line

```
sed 's/train/FOO/' testdat
```

vs

```
sed 's/train/FOO/g' testdat
```

which is a global replace

This is quite a bit more readable and less error-prone than some of the other possibilities, but of course there are applications which will not simplify quite as readily.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's;\(\(/[^/]\+\)*\)/train\(\(/[^/]\+\)*\)\.wav;\1/FOO\3.wav;'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it does not change the sample input (at least on MacOS X 10.6.7).

Comment: sed does not modify input, "sed" stands for "Stream EDitor" and streams are not writable.

first thing you'll do is ''man sed'' and read how your specific version works, you may or may not have a way to alter the file and if you don't create a temporary one and replace the original with it.

Comment: apologies for being marginally inaccurate...you are right. I should have said: if it is given the sample input, your sed script does not produce any changes, so the output is the same as the input (at least with the MacOS X). I can modify what you wrote to make it work as an extended regex (ERE) like this: `sed -E 's;((/[^/]+)*)/train((/[^/]+)*)\.wav;\1/FOO\3.wav;'`, where the main change is a reduction in the number of backslashes. Since the question is 10 months old and the original questioner has not clarified the question, it is going to be hard to know for sure what was wanted.

Comment: oh that's not what I meant (also I didn't realize you weren't the OP sorry) what I was trying to say is that sed doesn't alter the file itself but instead prints to stdin, however if it prints the exact same contents of the file it's definitely not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
sed -e 's/\<train\>/plane/g'
```

The `\<` tells sed to match the beginning of that work and the `\>` tells it to match the end of the word.

The `g` at the end means global so it performs the match and replace on the entire line and does not stop after the first successful match as it would normally do without `g`.